# Find a highest value in a set of columns and retrieve value in the respective row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have this set of columns, say A-Z. Each has thousands of records. I am trying to figure out the following: find the highest value among columns B-Z and retrieve the value of column A for that record.
Sounds simple but so far, I have not been able to find a solution not requiring VBScripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method without vba is to use a helper column:

In AA2 put:

```
=MAX(B2:Z2)
```

And copy down.

[image]

Then you can use an INDEX/MATCH to find the correct row:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(AA:AA),AA:AA,0))
```

[image]

The use of a helper column removes the need for an array type formula.  With as many data points as you suggested an array formula would be slow and possibly crash excel.

---

If you want to try to do it in one formula then try this:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$778,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$778)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(MAX($B$2:$Z$778)=$B$2:$Z$778),1))
```

Change the Rows and Columns to match your dataset.